# Is there any method available to check element in xml before accessing it in erlang?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd-module

```
EncodedData = xmpp:encode(Packet),
io:format("~n EncodedData => ~p~n", [EncodedData]),
{_, Id} = fxml:get_tag_attr(<<"id">>, EncodedData),
{_, To_Jid} = fxml:get_tag_attr(<<"to">>, EncodedData),
{_, From_Jid} = fxml:get_tag_attr(<<"from">>, EncodedData),
{_, Type} = fxml:get_tag_attr(<<"type">>, EncodedData),
```

I am successfully able to read data from the XML as shown above. In some cases the **type** field is not present in the **Packet** so the **EncodedData** also don't have **type** element in it and when ever I try to access that element the code crashed with an error of

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value false
   in function  mod_http_offline:create_message/1 (/opt/fp-backend-chat/ejabberd-modules/mod_http_offline.erl, line 38)
   in call from ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4 (src/ejabberd_hooks.erl, line 236)
   in call from ejabberd_hooks:run_fold1/4 (src/ejabberd_hooks.erl, line 217)
   in call from ejabberd_sm:route/1 (src/ejabberd_sm.erl, line 146)
   in call from ejabberd_router:do_route/1 (src/ejabberd_router.erl, line 399)
   in call from ejabberd_router:route/1 (src/ejabberd_router.erl, line 92)
   in call from ejabberd_c2s:check_privacy_then_route/2 (src/ejabberd_c2s.erl, line 865)
   in call from xmpp_stream_in:process_authenticated_packet/2 (src/xmpp_stream_in.erl, line 714)
```

is there any method to find that the accessing element is present in the encoded xml or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should use the xmpp library, not the lower-level fxml. For example, `xmpp:get_type/1`, see:
https://github.com/processone/xmpp/blob/master/doc/API.md#get_type1

Answer (score 1):

You should use `case` for that:

```erlang
case fxml:get_tag_attr(<<"type">>, EncodedData) of
  false -> ...;
  {_, Type} ->...
end
```